# Credit History and Outstanding Debts in Hungary

Tags: credit-history, hungary

I would like to check the credit history and any outstanding debt (if any) of a person in Hungary. Is there any service that I could contact?

I would like to assess if he or she has a good reputation financially, and if he or she has any financial trouble with private institutions as well as with public ones. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Do you have her permission to do so? Here's some more info: http://www.bisz.hu/en/node/60

Comment: @MichaelC. Thank you for the link. It seems a good reply; if you post it, I will accept it as an answer. For what concern the permission, I have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears all you have to do is [submit a form](http://www.bisz.hu/en/node/60). It might be better if she submitted it herself instead of you doing it on her behalf.

> All natural persons (individuals) and non-natural persons (businesses)
>   are entitled to access and inspect the data held on record about them
>   in the Central Credit Information System (KHR).